# can the jQuery UI automatically set the style?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use the `.button()` method to set the style of buttons and other input elements.

But when I use javascript to create any other button, I need to call the `.button()` method again.

Can the jQuery UI automatically set the style like the `.live()` method (it can automatically set the event).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge, this is not possible.

If you see yourself having to write `.button()` everywhere, consider writing a function to encapsulate that behaviour yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this little plugin will help you out:

http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs

But i have not had any chance of testing it with the latest jquery release.